# Deactivating layer on loading map using OSM Buildings in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to use OSMBuildings in my Leaflet map.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>OSM Buildings Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet-src.js"></script>
  <script src="../tools/OSMBuildings/osmbuildings-0.1.9a/tests/scripts.js.php?engine=Leaflet"></script>
  <style>
  body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
  }
  html, body, #map {
                 height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
   <script>

  // *** create OSM layer ... ***
  var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    { attribution: 'Map data <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }
    );

  // *** create MapQuest layer ... ***
  var mapquestUrl = 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  var subDomains = ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4'];
  var mapquestAttrib = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>,<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors';
  var mapquest = new L.TileLayer(mapquestUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: mapquestAttrib, subdomains: subDomains});

  // *** create map object and controls ... ***
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: [42, 12],
      zoom: 6,
      zoomControl: false,
      layers: [mapquest]
  });
  var zoomControl = new L.Control.Zoom({position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);    

  // *** add osmBuilding layer ... ***
  var osmBuildingsLayer = new OSMBuildings(map).loadData();

  // *** create base layers list ... ***
  var baseLayers = {
            "MapQuest OSM": mapquest,
    "OpenStreetMap": osm,
  };

  // *** create overlay layers list ... ***
  var overlays = {
    "OSM Buildings": osmBuildingsLayer,
  };

  // *** add base layers and overlay layers list to map ... ***
  TOC = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays);
  TOC.addTo(map);



  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

All is working but in my `L.control.layers`, I note that the layer "OSM Buildings" starts activated and I'd like to have it deactivated.

How do I do it?

[You can test it](http://www.cesaregerbino.com/ItalyOpenAddresses/OSM-Buildings-Test.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checkbox is just a wrapper for the addLayer/removeLayer method. As you've already added the layer the checkbox is checked.

If you go to the console and do:

```
map.removeLayer(osmBuildingsLayer)
```

The checkbox will uncheck. Then go back and do:

```
map.addLayer(osmBuildingsLayer)
```

It will be checked again. If you want it off at load time just call removeLayer.